# repeat asynchronous $http get until condition holds true

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs, scrape

**Background:**

- I am using node.js and a module called scrap (with jQuery) to screen scrape a website and display some of its information on my own website
- To do this, I am making a JSON of data available at a certain path in my website so that the client can retrieve the information when they load the client-side javascript
- I am exporting a variable in the JSON called isLoaded that will be true if the server has finished loading all of the data for the json

**Problem:**

- Since scrap and jquery make asynchronous calls and load them into the data variable that is sent with the JSON, all of the information might not be included in the JSON just yet
- This is fine most of the time, but take for instance the example when I access the page that loads that data and the server is still populating the data that is exported with the JSON object
- This essentially requires the client to refresh the page until all of the data is loaded.

**Question:**

Is there a way to continuously call $http.get(...path...) inside the client-side javascript until the variable 'isLoaded' returns true?

**Note:**

I have already tried a loop but for some reason the loop can't get new data once it's running. Also, I have tried to the best of my ability to find an answer on Google with no luck. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You would probably be better off using `Socket.io` to have the server send a notification when the content is ready...

Comment: you could use a longpoll/comet request to wait for a response from the server, and the response handler will simply set a "done" flag to true when the server's done. that'll keep your "is it done yet" checking purely on the client without having to poke the server every X seconds.

Comment: it is better to user socket.io or longpoll as other said, but you can easily do what you ask for by making a recursive call from ajax sucess method after checking the condition.

Comment: Recursive calls seemed to do it. Thanks!